# Setting default background with android canvas and invalidate()

Tags: android, canvas, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I've created a bounce ball game and I want to apply a background to it. Currently, I was using a solid color background but I want to switch to an image.

I tried to make use of the following code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
```

And it works fine. But it makes game a lot sluggish than before. Previously, the physics was smooth with high framerate, but with this background, its like I'm running Android emulator on 1GB RAM PC.

I want to ask what is the most efficient way to put a default canvas background as I wouldn't change it. Also, since I'm calling `invalidate();` it redraws canvas again and again so I feel its waste to update background each time.

Comment: Instead of drawing the background on the canvas is it possible to just set an ImageView behind the View that you are using as the canvas? This way its only drawn once.

Comment: @Darussian but for that I've to set background of canvas to be transparent. Is it transparent by default?

Comment: Yup, you should be able to just draw over the Imageview